# Does curl require a header for API authentication, in a GET call?

Tags: api, authentication, curl

For an example:

Here is a question on using the curl to query an order from ShippingEasy restful API:

Created string for API signature per their direction ([https://shippingeasy.readme.io/docs/authentication-signing-requests]) as below: `GET&/api/orders&api_key=xxx&api_timestamp=1601121474,&order_number=123456`

Use the above string and the api secret key(private key) to obtained a signature(sss) using HMAC SHA265.
Then executed curl command as below, per their direction ([https://shippingeasy.readme.io/docs/creating-a-signature](https://shippingeasy.readme.io/docs/authentication-signing-requests))

```
curl "https://app.shippingeasy.com/api/orders?api_key=xxx&api_signature=sss&api_timestamp=1601121474,&order_number=123456
```

However, curl is returning `{"errors":[{"message":"Access denied.","status":401}]}`

The PST time zone to calculate the unix epoch time.  ShippingEasy is located in Texas (central time zone).

I have already verify the HMAC SHA265 method that generates the signature, using the https://www.liavaag.org/English/SHA-Generator/HMAC/ site.

Thank you in advance for helping.